# Finding Hamiltonian paths with Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

Can Dijkstra algorithm find all shortest path from a single source vertex to all other vertices such that the path visits all the vertices in an undirected and symmetric graph once and exactly once? Is there a faster algorithm for the symmetric graph?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want?

Comment: Are you allowed to visit vertices multiple times, or does it have to be exactly once?

Comment: @templatetypedef: No multiple times only each vertex once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is an algorithm to find the shortest [Hamiltonian paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) from a single node to each other node in the graph (a Hamiltonian path is one that passes through every node in the graph exactly once).  Unfortunately, the problem of even determining whether or not there *is* a Hamiltonian path between a pair of nodes in an undirected graph is NP-complete, and so there are no known polynomial-time algorithms that solve this problem (and they don't exist unless P = NP).  Since Dijkstra's algorithm runs in polynomial time, there is no known modification to this algorithm that will find Hamiltonian paths to each other node in the graph.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Dijkstra's algorithm will help you to find out the shortest path in both directed and undirected graphs. But it is more useful when directed graph is used.

Bellman-Ford algorithm can be faster than Dijsktra's, but only in few cases and this algorithm is valid for graphs with negative cycle.

Simplest implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm results in running time for O(|E|+|V|^2). [|E| & |V| denoting the edges and vertices of a graph.

Comment: Is there an algorithm like dijkstra but it visit all vertex not all shortest-path?

Comment: Isn't that just O(V^2), as E is limited by V^2?

Comment: I think the OP's question is about finding Hamiltonian paths with Dijkstra's algorithm, not just finding arbitrary shortest paths.

Comment: @Phpdna ~ Sorry for absence. Do you mean Floyd-Warshall algorithm? This algorithm will visit all the vertices and aim to find the shortest distance between each pair of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra algorithm finds the shortest path from one selected point to all the others. It's defined for a graph (either directed or not) with non-negative edges. For this case there's no faster algorithm.

If there are constraints on the edge weights - there may be faster algorithm. For instance, if the weights are limited to [0,1] - the BFS algorithm can be used.

This can be generalized to a case with integer weights, one may also use a faster algorithm. (i.e. instead of using a binary search tree one may use a limited set of arrays).

Comment: How is the complexity of dijkstra? I don't need all shortest-path? Or do I need to use a simplex algorithm or somethin else when I just want the shortest-path but with all vertex?

Comment: @sukunrt Yes I think that's probably the answer although it is a little hard to tell what's required.